# Variable error of SQLite in Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

There is some error on my SQLite.

```
03-18 16:12:09.720: E/SQLiteLog(27137): (1) near "type": syntax error
03-18 16:12:09.720: W/dalvikvm(27137): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c20450)
03-18 16:12:09.740: E/AndroidRuntime(27137): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
```

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_OWNER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_BUS + "(" + KEY_ROUTE + " TEXT NOT NULL," + KEY_DESTINATION + " TEXT NOT NULL," + KEY_FEE + " TEXT NOT NULL " + KEY_TYPE + " TEXT NOT NULL " + KEY_VIA1 + " TEXT NOT NULL " + KEY_VIA2 + " TEXT NOT NULL " + KEY_VIA3 + " TEXT NOT NULL );";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_OWNER_TABLE);
}
```

Comment: is there any field name `type` u are using ?

Answer (score 2):

You are missing commas.

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_OWNER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_BUS + "(" + KEY_ROUTE + " TEXT NOT NULL," + KEY_DESTINATION + " TEXT NOT NULL," + KEY_FEE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_TYPE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_VIA1 + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_VIA2 + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_VIA3 + " TEXT NOT NULL );";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_OWNER_TABLE);
}
```

Comment: This guy is the winner here.

Comment: Please don't forget to choose the answer help you most :)

Comment: @user3336747, You should accept this answer by ticking green tick mark besides this answer. This helps others as well.

Answer (score 2):

There should be a comma between two column declaration like below,

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
{
    String CREATE_OWNER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_BUS + "(" + KEY_ROUTE + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
             KEY_DESTINATION + " TEXT NOT NULL," + 
             KEY_FEE + " TEXT NOT NULL ," +   // Missing comma here
             KEY_TYPE + " TEXT NOT NULL ," +  // Missing comma here
             KEY_VIA1 + " TEXT NOT NULL ," +  // Missing comma here
             KEY_VIA2 + " TEXT NOT NULL ," +  // Missing comma here
             KEY_VIA3 + " TEXT NOT NULL );";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_OWNER_TABLE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please insert commas as below,

```
     public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
String CREATE_OWNER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_BUS + "(" + KEY_ROUTE + " TEXT NOT NULL," + KEY_DESTINATION + " TEXT NOT NULL," + KEY_FEE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_TYPE + " TEXT NOT NULL ," + KEY_VIA1 + " TEXT NOT NULL ," + KEY_VIA2 + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_VIA3 + " TEXT NOT NULL );";
db.execSQL(CREATE_OWNER_TABLE);
```

}